# Is it possible to re-use react-native-maps markers outside of a MapView?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm building a React Native app which allows user to create both "world maps" with a MapView and "local maps" from an image file. Users are then able to place pins on those maps.

I'd like to re-use the  component from react-native-maps, but it's look like it's not rendering when outside of a MapView. I've tried setting it's absolute position from CSS and using the centerOffset prop, but none seem to be working.

Any ideas or solutions that could look similar ?

````
```javascript
    <ImageBackground
        style={{aspectRatio: value.width / value.height}}
        source={{uri}}>
        {extra.length > 0 &&
        extra.map((marker, index) => (
        <Marker
        style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: marker.coordinates.y,
            left: marker.coordinates.x,
        }}
        pinColor={this.findColor(marker, buttons)}
        />
    </ImageBackground>
```
````

Best, Jules